# Flink 1.4 throws errors

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

just trying to migrate from flink 1.3 into 1.4 and getting this exception on 
linux machine:
(not reproducing at windows).

i've import this package also:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-shaded-hadoop2
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-shaded-hadoop2', version: '1.4.0'
```

any help?

at flink console:

```
TriggerWindow(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(10000), ReducingStateDescriptor{serializer=org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.TupleSerializer@cb6c5dba, reduceFunction=com.clicktale.reducers.MetricsReducer@4e406694}, ProcessingTimeTrigger(), WindowedStream.reduce(WindowedStream.java:241)) -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1)



    java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2375)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFsFactory.create(HadoopFsFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:401)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.createHadoopFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:1154)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initializeState(BucketingSink.java:355)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeOperators(StreamTask.java:694)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:682)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar (not specifically this, but dependencies related) issues migrating from 1.3 to 1.4.

In my case, I had to re-generate a fresh POM file using maven archetype and then add the needed dependencies one by one. 
See [Java Quickstart](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html) or [Scala Quickstart](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/quickstart/scala_api_quickstart.html).

Reason being that there has been a major rework on dependency structure. See [Release notes](https://flink.apache.org/news/2017/12/12/release-1.4.0.html#a-significantly-improved-dependency-structure-and-reversed-class-loading) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Flink 1.4 will load any Hadoop jars found via the "hadoop classpath" shell command, and these will be first on the classpath. So if you have an incompatible version of Hadoop installed that the "hadoop" command points at, you can run into this kind of problem.